How to solve Aurora assertion failure Error
I am getting:

ERROR: ORA-29516: Aurora assertion failure: Assertion failure at joez.c:6725
jit-to-interpreter trampoline botch: invoker-index 8634 too large for com/glob/asd/FinalTest

While my code is like:
c = Class.forName ("com.glob.asd.Final" + objectName);   //load class
cd = c.newInstance(); // instantiate

I think I am getting error while loading the class due to JIT compiler.
In my opinion it was due to some memory issues. So I am trying to find the root cause of this error and need some info regarding the error and how to solve this.
